# how to deal with japanese word using python xlrd 

Tags: python, xlrd

this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python   
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-   

import xlrd,sys,re

data = xlrd.open_workbook('a.xls',encoding_override="utf-8")
a = data.sheets()[0]
s=''
for i in range(a.nrows):
    if 9<i<20:
        #stage
        print a.row_values(i)[1].decode('shift_jis')+'\n'
```

but it show :

```
????
????????
??????
????
????
????
????????
```

so what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: It looks like you're reading the file as UTF-8, then trying to interpret something as Shift JIS?  I'd not expect that to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background: In a "modern" (Excel 97-2003) XLS file, text is effectively stored as Unicode. In older files, text is stored as 8-bit strings, and a "codepage" record tells how it is encoded e.g. the integer 1252 corresponds to the encoding known as `cp1252` or `windows-1252`. In either case, `xlrd` presents extracted text as unicode objects.

Please insert this line into your code:

```
print data.biff_version, data.codepage, data.encoding
```

If you have a new file, you should see

```
80 1200 utf_16_le
```

In any case, please edit your question to report the outcome.

Problem 1: `encoding_override` is required ONLY if the file is an old file AND you know/suspect that the codepage record is omitted or wrong. It is ignored if the file is a new file. Do you really know that the file is pre-Excel-97 and the text is encoded in UTF-8? If so, it can only have been created by some seriously deluded 3rd-party software, and Excel will blow up if you try to open it with Excel; visit the author with a baseball bat. Otherwise, don't use encoding_override.

Problem 2: You *should* have `unicode` objects. To display them, you need to **encode** (*not decode*) them from `unicode` to `str` using a suitable encoding. It is very suprising that `print unicode_object.decode('shift-jis')` doesn't raise an exception and prints question marks.

To help understand this, please change your code to be like this:

```
text = a.rowvalues(i)[1]
print i, repr(text)
print repr(text.decode('shift-jis'))
```

and report the outcome.

So that we can help you choose an appropriate encoding (if any), tell us what version of what operating system you are using, and what the following display:

```
print sys.stdout.encoding
import locale
print locale.getpreferredencoding()
```

Further reading:

(1) the xlrd documentation (section on Unicode, right up the front) ... included in the distribution, or get the latest commit [here](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html).

(2) the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't your encoding override on open shift-jis?

```
data = xlrd.open_workbook('a.xls',encoding_override="shift-jis")
```

If the file is really shift-JIS, there are *lots* of code points (well frankly, almost all of them) that don't overlap with valid UTF-8 code points.  If you are getting illegal characters (?) and your file is really UTF-8 and you want to output Shift-JIS, might I suggest that your output shell (for print - probably a file would be fine) can't handle the encoding.